# How do I do calculations in a separate method then send them back to main for printing?

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I am trying to do the calculations for the interest in another method, and I know that I have to make another method outside of main and then put return an the end, but I have no idea what to title this new method and how to go about doing the calculations there. I think it is the while loop that is confusing me. I have done this once before on a different project, so I have an idea of how to do it, but this project isn't anything like the other one and I don't really understand it. Any help is extremely appreciated as I have been working on this for a long time and just want to get it over with. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.Scanner; // This allows for the use of the scanner in the class

public class SavingsAccount // Start of class
{
    public static void main(String[]args) // Start of main
    {
        double P; // These store the amounts that will be used in the accruing interest formula
        double i;
        double n;
        double S = 0;
        int timesLooped = 0;
        Scanner readConsole = new Scanner(System.in); // This is the scanner

        System.out.println("I am a savings account interest calculator."); // Prompts the user for input
        System.out.println("How much money have you deposited?");
        P = readConsole.nextDouble();
        S = P;
        System.out.println("Now, what is the annual interest rate? (i.e. .05)");
        i = readConsole.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Finally, how long do you plan on having the money in the account?");
        n = readConsole.nextDouble();
        while (timesLooped <= n)
        {
            S = S + (P * i);
            timesLooped += 1;
        }
        System.out.println("Your balance in that time span is " + S + "."); // Tells you your ending balance
    }

}
```

Comment: Which part do you want to put in a separate method, and why?

Comment: The calculation at the bottom S=S + (P * 1)      and because I'm trying to learn

Comment: On an unrelated note, your loop executes one too many times. (E.g., put in 100, 0.05, and 0. The result should be 100, but it's 105, because the loop executes too many times. Use `timesLooped < n` instead to fix.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, I think you want this:

```
private static double addInterest(double S, double P, double i)
{
    return S + (P * i);
}

...

public static void main()
{
    ...
    while (timesLooped <= n)
    {
        S = addInterest(S, P, i);
    }
```

**EDIT**

I made some small improvements just for fun:

1. I put the entire interest calculation into the function and used exponentiation rather than a loop.
2. I gave the variables more descriptive names.
3. I used `System.out.format` to print the result.

Here's the code:

```
private static double computeCompoundInterest(double principal, double rate,
                                              double years) {
    return principal * Math.pow(1 + rate, years);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("I am a savings account interest calculator.");

    System.out.println("How much money have you deposited?");
    double principal = scanner.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Now, what is the annual interest rate? (i.e. .05)");
    double rate = scanner.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("How many years will you hold that money in the account?");
    double years = scanner.nextDouble();

    double total = computeCompoundInterest(principal, rate, years);

    System.out.format("Your balance at the end of that period will be %.2f.\n", years, total);
}
```

Comment: it's giving me an error on the S and i in the new private method and an error on addInterest in the while loop. Any ideas? PS I very much appreciate your help

Comment: I made an edit not long ago... make sure you have `double S, double P, double i`.

Comment: It works! I appreciate it more than you know. Thank you very much

Comment: @AsaNam Happy to help. I also added a slightly different version of the code as an edit, just FYI!

Comment: I will definitely take a look at that. Thanks again!